# Upgrade Current Target to IPhone Not IPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, upgrade, universal

I currently have an ipad app and would now like to turn it into a universal app for both iPad and iPhone. The problem is I cant seem to find the feature to upgrade my iPad app to universal. There is an option to go from iPhone to iPad but not the other way around.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new target and chose what kind of devices you want to deploy on:
iPhone, iPad or Universal

See the screenshot below:
[image]